# How to convert 240 VAC to 240 VDC

Tags: solar-energy, mppt

I have a few questions, namely:

1. I aim to charge a 220 VDC battery pack with solar panels producing 240 VDC when open circuit using an MPPT charger. Where may I get such an MPPT charger?
2. I'd like to charge a 220 VDC battery bank with a 220 VAC generator used as back up power. Then I need to convert a 220 VDC power supply back to 220 VAC to power domestic appliances. How is this done?

Comment: Hi, Nick, and welcome. Shouting in your question title will get your question extra attention - but not the sort you'll want. I recommend that you fix it. Also, be aware that seeking product recommendations and places to purchase them are not allowed and will result in your question being closed fairly promptly. (Take the [Tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour).) You'll need to fix that too.

Comment: Your question title and body don't seem to be about the same thing. You're asking about AC-DC conversion in the title, but then you're asking about DC-DC conversion and AC-DC-AC UPS design.

Answer (score 2):

I am very much confused by your question. I haven't seen a 220-volt battery bank for solar panels. The battery bank usually consists of 12-volt batteries. And the MPPT charger is widely available.Like in [Alibaba](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Lumiax-12V-24V-40A-MPPT-Solar_60714297192.html?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.0.0.61412440A6KfGr) , [Ali Express](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33031877382.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.128920b7OP41G2&algo_pvid=23546a13-09e1-4a01-8930-4563ab71d585&algo_expid=23546a13-09e1-4a01-8930-4563ab71d585-10&btsid=0ab6f81e15849177261326089e23da&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)

And I prefer not to connect solar panels such a way that it produces 220-volt DC. Rather keep it within 24 - 48 volt. Otherwise, you won't get any solar charge controller in the market.

Answer (score 1):

Since battery charging is involved, you will want to confine yourself to COTS equipment.  Battery charging is highly complex and doesn't lend itself to homebrew equipment.

Sadat Rafi is exactly correct that a 220V battery pack is going to limit your options in terms of battery chargers and charge controllers.  Also, 220V DC is a very nasty customer - it's not your pleasant friendly 12 volts DC. Once a 220VDC arc gets struck, it does not know pity or remorse or fear and cannot be stopped unless killed.

As far as selecting array voltage, you should also be mindful of Rapid Shutdown requirements, which are about protecting firemen from electric shock from solar arrays mounted on a roof or other workspace for firemen. The threshold voltages for Rapid Shutdown are 30V and 80V in North America, and will vary worldwide.

Comment: Islanding may be a term used elsewhere for Rapid Shutdown...